# Transalating WooCommerce checkout page from English to Polish

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I don't have much experience with Wordpress. I am working more with vanilla php.

I wish to translate my website from English to Polish.
99% of WooCommerce is fine but there are few strings I can't overwrite with my function and it looks unprofessional.

I am using php 8
Wordpress - the newest ver.
Astra theme Version 6.1.1
The newest Woocommerce
Polylang Version 3.1.3
Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration Version 1.5.0

https://undziabundzia.com/platnosc/ You can see strings like "Yes, I'm ok with you sending me additional newsletter and email content" that are not reacting to my code:

```
/**
 * Translation of untranslated
 */

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($uri,'platnosc') != false) {
    add_filter('gettext', 'translate_strings');
    add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_strings');
    function translate_strings($translated) {
        $translated = str_ireplace('Local pickup', 'Odbior osobisty', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Direct bank transfer ', 'Przelew tradycyjny', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Cash on delivery', 'Odbior osobisty', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Your personal data will be used to process your order, support your experience throughout this website, and for other purposes described in our', 'Twoje dane osobowe zostaną wykorzystane do przetworzenia Twojego zamówienia, poprawienia Twojego doświadczenia na tej stronie oraz do innych celów opisanych w naszym', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace("Yes, I'm ok with you sending me additional newsletter and email content", "Tak, zgadzam się na przesłanie mi dodatkowego newslettera i treści e-mail", $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('My contact', 'Mój kontakt', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Shipping method', 'Sposób dostawy', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Shipping to', 'Dostawa do', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Change', 'Zmień', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('Make your payment directly into our bank account. Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order will not be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.', 'Dokonaj płatności bezpośrednio na nasze konto bankowe. Użyj swojego identyfikatora zamówienia jako numeru referencyjnego płatności. Twoje zamówienie nie zostanie wysłane, dopóki środki nie zostaną rozliczone na naszym koncie.', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace("Yes, I'm ok with you sending me additional newsletter and email content", "Tak, zgadzam się na przesłanie mi dodatkowego newslettera i treści e-mail", $translated);
        return $translated;
    }
}
```

It looks like at first my function works, but is later overwritten by JSON or something.

Answer (score 0):

how about php code

```
function custom_wc_translations($translated){
    $text = array(
    'Your order' => 'Your new phrase',
    'any other string' => 'New string',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20 );
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#your_my_order_element_id').html('Your New string');
//$('.your_my_order_element_class').html('Your New string');
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```